# Null Pointer Exception in getGraphics() for BufferedImage?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedimage

```
public void saveImage(String path){
    BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) createImage(500, 500);
    Graphics gImage = image.getGraphics(); //<<<<<<<<--- exception
    paint(gImage);
    image = image.getSubimage(0,0,500,500);     
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(path+".png"));
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Where is the problem ??

Comment: Thanks, but i need more help .. 
i am using a timer to display an arraylist of JPanels, when the timer is stopped the method .isDisplayable() returns false and the exception appears, otherwise the image is saved ... so what should i do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NPE is probably not coming from getGraphics but from trying to dereference a null `image` variable. If your component is not displayable, `createImage` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the method `createImage(int, int)` is returning `null`. The reason is explained in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29):

> **Returns:**
>   an off-screen drawable image, which can be used for double buffering. 
>   The return value may be null if the component is not displayable. This will
>   always happen if GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns true.